# Load balancing among multiple PPPoE servers

Tags: pppoe, load-balancing

What are the possible and efficient ways to load-balance users among multiple PPPoE servers?

I have tried with VRRP. Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: Have you looked at appliances which specifically do load balancing for servers?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

PPPoE it's a L2 protocol, you cannot use a L3 redundancy protocol like VRRP. You can put how many PPPoE server as you want on the same broadcast domain and the redundancy will be guaranteed. The client send the PADI in broadcast, every BRAS reply with PADO but the client will discard all PADO packets except the first one. If your server has some advanced features like PADO delay,  use them for have the control of BRAS selection

Comment: What do you mean about "load balancing"? PPPoE is a L2 stateful protocol, then it's (almost) impossible to load balance. What is your detailed use case?